# Почему флаг Qt:: WindowMaximizeButtonHint выставляет QDialog поверх родительского QMainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Есть главное окно (QMainWindow) и дополнительное окошко на QDialog.
Есть необходимость убрать кнопку "хелп" и добавить кнопку "развернуть" (для QDialog).

Главное окно :

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QObject* ptrBox, QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    informla(new InformLA(this)),

{
//....
}
```

informla (QDialog):

```
InformLA::InformLA(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::InformLA)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setWindowFlags(this->windowFlags() & Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint & ~Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint);
//.......
}
```

Строка `this->setWindowFlags(this->windowFlags() & Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint & ~Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint);` а именно флаг `Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint` совершает следующее: QDialog появляется прямо на родительском окне:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я же ожидаю от него другого поведения.. Без этого флага всё работает нормально, он(диалог) открывается как нужно (отдельным окном, когда его вызывают).
В чем моя ошибка? Спасибо

Comment: `s/informla(new InformLA(this))/informla(new InformLA)/` — при указании родителя виджету он создаётся как часть родительского, а не как отдельное окно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this->setWindowFlags(this->windowFlags() 
    | Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint           // set bit to 1
    & (~Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint));   // set bit to 0
```

У вас проблема с битовыми операциями. Чтобы установить бит в 1, надо использовать  `| ...`. Чтобы установить бит в 0, надо использовать `&(~...)`

Comment: К тому же, с 5.9 версии есть метод ``QWidget::setWindowFlag(Qt::WindowType flag, bool on = true)`` которым можно пользоваться чтоб не заморачиватся с битовой логикой

Comment: Всем большое спасибо